# android - passing data to main activity from class

Tags: android, facebook, listview, android-activity, handler

I'm trying to implement a facebook app according to the example in the [facebook-android-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/) . 
I'm changing it a little bit and I'm having a difficult about someting which is very basic.

I'm having my main activity which shows the facebook places near me.
thats the code at mainActivity.java

```
private void getFBPlaces()
{
   fbObject.fetchPlaces();

   // NOW I want to fill my listview with the results.....
   // someting like
   placesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.places_list);
   placesList.setOnItemClickListener(Places.this);
   placesList.setAdapter(new PlacesListAdapter(Places.this));

}
```

this is the relevant code from FBObject.java see the TODO

```
private void fetchPlaces() {
    /*
     * Source tag: fetch_places_tag
     */
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("type", "place");
    try {
        params.putString("center",
                location.getString("latitude") + "," + location.getString("longitude"));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        showToast("No places fetched.");
        return;
    }
    params.putString("distance", "1000");
    Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("search", params, new placesRequestListener());
}

/*
 * Callback after places are fetched.
 */
public class placesRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

    @Override
    public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
        Log.d("Facebook-FbAPIs", "Got response: " + response);
        dialog.dismiss();

        try {
            jsonArray = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("data");
            if (jsonArray == null) {
                showToast("Error: nearby places could not be fetched");
                return;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            showToast("Error: " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // TODO: I want to return the result to main activity
                .....
            }
        });

    }
```

got any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do this is passing the activity instance to the  PlacesRequestListener and, in the complete callback, do something like "activity.findViewById(R.id.places_list)" to get the list. From here you can set the adapter.
Of course that the method needs to be running on the main thread in order to be able to manipulate the UI

Comment: Is it possible to make your jsonarray static and just access it from inside your Handler? Not sure if this would work, just an idea

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the new v3.0b of the Android SDK. In particular, it has a built-in place picker that will help accelerate what you are trying to do here.

You'll find it at http://developers.facebook.com/android